# Automate passing JBOSS installer arguments using Expect Command

Tags: bash, shell-script, expect, systemd-nspawn, jboss

I have a JBOSS Installer which when run manually it will prompt for input and below is the sample of the execution is as below

```
[sp@sp baseInstaller]$ ./advStart.sh config
Buildfile: /home/sp/jboss/sp/baseInstaller/build.xml

init:

config:
   [groovy] coa.install.props properties
   [groovy]
   [groovy]   ? indicates a response is required from you
   [groovy]   [value] is the current value
   [groovy]        to keep current value just press <enter>
   [groovy]        or type new value and press <enter>
   [groovy]   {value,value..} shows the allowed values
   [groovy] installer version 6.0.3.4
   [groovy]
   [groovy] Jboss Server Config Options (changeable after initial config)
   [groovy] -------------------------------------------------------------
   [groovy] ? host                        [sp.resource.com]
resource.com
   [groovy]     ip=10.50.55.90
   [groovy]   host changed to resource.com
   [groovy] ? bind to host only or all ports (all has security implications)
   [groovy]                               [host]
   [groovy]                                                  {host,all,custom}
all
   [groovy]   bind to host only or all ports (all has security implications) changed to all
   [groovy] ? min memory                  [64]
64
```

I tried to frame an expect script to automate this process and below is my script

```
[sp@sp baseInstaller]$ cat saba.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect


# Accessing command line arguments
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
set arg2 [lindex $argv 1]

# Printing the arguments
puts "Argument 1: $arg1"
puts "Argument 2: $arg2"

cd /home/sp/jboss/sp/baseInstaller
spawn ./advStart.sh config

# Expect the prompt for the argument with a timeout of 10 seconds
expect {
        "? host                        [sp.resource.com]" {
        # Send the host value
        send "$arg1\r"
        exp_continue
        }
    "? bind to host only or all ports (all has security implications)" {
        # Send the argument value
        send "$arg2\r"
    }
    timeout {
        puts "Error: Timed out while waiting for the prompt."
        exit 1
    }
    eof
} -timeout 10

# Wait for the script to finish
wait
```

Now while executing this script, it is getting struck in the below place and not proceeding further. Can you please help me about this?

```
[sp@sp baseInstaller]$ expect saba.sh resource.com all
Argument 1: resource.com
Argument 2: all
spawn ./advStart.sh config
Buildfile: /home/sp/jboss/sp/baseInstaller/build.xml

init:

config:
   [groovy] coa.install.props properties
   [groovy]
   [groovy]   ? indicates a response is required from you
   [groovy]   [value] is the current value
   [groovy]        to keep current value just press <enter>
   [groovy]        or type new value and press <enter>
   [groovy]   {value,value..} shows the allowed values
```

Answer (score 1):

`expect` is very strict about the form using `{}`. By adding the
superfluous `-timeout 10` after the `{}` it no longer recognises the
multiline `{}` format, and wrongly interprets the patterns to match. You
can see this if you run the script with debug (option `-d`).

Consider this simpler example:

```
expect {
  "abc" exit 1
} -timeout 10
```

You will see the debug

```
expect: does "" (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern "\n  "abc" exit 1\n"? no
"10"? no
```

As you can see, the pattern was taken to be everything between "{" and "}",
and "-timeout" was taken as the command to do if it matched. "10" is then
the next pattern to match.

Also, the pattern `"? host                        [sp.resource.com]"` will not match because by default the pattern is assumed to be a "glob", and so `[` is a special character beginning a set of characters. You need to prefix the pattern with `-ex` to mean an *exact match* is wanted. Make sure the whitespace matches exactly the data.

Comment: That sounds right. I tried to alter my code with basic expect commands as below
`expect "? host *"
send -- "$arg1\r"
expect "? bind to host only or all ports (all has security implications)\r"
send -- "$arg2\r"
expect eof`

The second argument is passed well, whereas the 1st Argument is getting passed at the wrong place, (i.e) after `config:` but it should come after the line that has got `? host   [*]` the pattern in square brackets will change as per the hostname this is executed on.
`Argument 1: resource.com
Argument 2: all
config:
resource.com`

Comment: Don't forget that the default timeout for each expect line is 10 seconds.
The program will move on to the next line if the pattern with host has not
been seen after this time. You can use `expect -timeout 20 "? host "` for
example. Using `*` at the end of a pattern is not often useful, as it can
match the empty string too. Run your script with `-d` to see what is happening.